# Mocking an anonymous callback

Tags: c#, moq

I have a method like:

```
    public class Args
    {
        public string Command {get;set;}
        public Action<string> LogHandler {get;set;}
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        IRunner mRunner;

        public MyClass(IRunner runner)
        {
            mRunner = runner;
        }

        public string GetVersionText()
        {
            List<string> log = new List<string>();
            Args args = new Args()
            {
                Command = "getversion",
                LogHandler = (msg) => { log.Add(msg); }
            };
            mRunner.Execute(args);
            return log.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("Version"));
        }
    }
```

I want to test different outputs being received, how would I mock the IRunner.Execute method so that I can control what it does with an Action property of the Args class?

Comment: How is `mRunner` populated normally? Is it set in the constructor? Please include the code.

Comment: @JohnWu an IRunner is passed into the class's constructor.

Comment: @Cuthbert You cant mock teh callback since it is being created within the subject under test. I would suggest that you capture the args in a Callback  and invoke the `args.LogHandler(your_msg_here)` within it (the callback)

Comment: Could you please amend your question to include the definition of `Args`? Your question mentions `Action` property but the provided code does not.  Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without that we can't help you.

Comment: @PeterCsala Updated with definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't  really mock the callback since it is being created within the subject under test.

I would suggest that you capture the `args` in a `Callback` and invoke the

```
args.LogHandler(your_msg_here)
```

within it (the callback)

Assuming `IRunner` is an injected dependency, a simple test based on the provided example above could look like this

```
// Arrange
string expected = "Message containing Version";
var runner = new Mock<IRunner>();
runner
    .Setup(_ => _.Execute(It.IsAny<Args>()))
    .Callback((Args args) => args.LogHandler(expected)); //<-- this will invoke the action

MyClass subject = new MyClass(runner.Object);

// Act
string actual = subject.GetVersionText();

//Assert - using Fluent Assertions
actual.Should().Be(expected);
```